# How to link to the page displayed by home.php?

Tags: theme-development, templates, template-hierarchy

I am working on a theme that is using front-page.php as a front-page.php and home.php to show blog posts. What I can't figure out is how to link to the blog page that is displayed with home.php.

Obviously if I set a specific page to display blog posts in the readings page, I can link to that page, but that doesn't solve the problem. I need a way to link to the page that setting points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the option `page_for_posts`:

```
get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
```